# Val Accuracy not increasing at all even through training loss is decreasing

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am training a model for image classification, my training accuracy is increasing and training loss is also decreasing but validation accuracy remains constant.

Here is my code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19 model= VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
        input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling=None, classes=1000) x=model.output

x=Conv2D(filters=1024,kernel_size=2)(x)
x=MaxPooling2D()(x) 
x=Flatten()(x) 
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) 
x=BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x) 
x=Dropout(0.8)(x) 
x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(x) 
x=Dense(4,activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=x)

for layer in model.layers[:12]:
   layer.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers[12:]:
   layer.trainable=True


opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6) 
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
           optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint_path="/content/drive/My Drive/Model/model_vgg19_6.h5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor="val_acc", mode="max", 
   save_best_only = True,verbose=1)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_acc', mode="max", factor = 0.7, 
     patience = 5, verbose = 1, min_delta =0.00001)

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_acc', mode="max", min_delta = 0, patience = 30, verbose = 1, 
            restore_best_weights = True)

callbacks = [reduce_lr,checkpoint]

model.fit_generator(aug_train, steps_per_epoch=int((len(data_x)/128)+1), validation_data= 
                (val_x,val_y), validation_steps=int((len(val_x)/128)+1), workers=-1, 
                use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True, epochs=300, callbacks=callbacks )
```

I am getting a constant val_acc of 0.24541
[image: Val Acc Result]

Answer (score 1):

You start with a VGG net that is [**pre-trained on ImageNet**](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg19) - this likely means the weights are not going to change a lot (without further modifications or drastically increasing the learning rate, for example).

If you are expecting the performance to increase on a pre-trained network, you are performing *fine-tuning*. There is a section on [**fine-tuning the Keras implementation of the InceptionV3 network**](https://keras.io/applications/#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes), but the principals are the same: you should freeze some of the earlier *feature-extraction* layers, leaving only some of the final layers marked as *trainable*. This is the example given in the docs, where they add new layers to the base model, train **only those layers** for a while, then additionally unfreeze some of the base model.

```
# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)   # <--- leave out final layers!
# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

-> run training for a few epochs
```

The some time later, unfreeze the part of the base model

```
# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will freeze
# the first 249 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:249]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[249:]:
   layer.trainable = True
```

Please looked at the full documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, actually I missed that code block while posting that question. I have frozen the first 12 layers and fine-tuned the remaining 12 layers. But my validation accuracy is not increasing.